# How do you extend Kendo UI widgets

Tags: widget, extend, kendo-ui

I couldn't find any official documentation about extending Kendo UI widgets or making composite controls on Kendo UI's website. 
Are there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm about to write a post on this, but you can checkout the following project on GitHub for creating plugins.  Currently there is a composite control for this...

https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins

Here is a live fiddle example of a compositing an AutoComplete and a ListView...

http://jsfiddle.net/burkeholland/G2f4a/embedded/result/

```
// thanks for making put a useless comment here stackoverflow
```

Comment: And now we are talking...:-) only reason I didn't start to use kendoui was because I couldn't find how to extend. Great work. Thanks Holland.

Comment: Can't edit the post because it wants code with the fiddle link. The updated link to kendo-plugins: https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins

Comment: Could you please help me with this quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545368/extend-kendo-multiselect

Answer (score 7):

There's official documentation now:
[How to Create a Custom Widget](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/create-custom-kendo-widget)

Here's a link to semi-official [community plugins](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins).

And here are some [examples](https://github.com/jsExtensions/kendoui-extended-api)  of widgets created by John DeVight.

[An SO post showing a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494360/2001735) which extends the mobile list view.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer today. However, the link above doesn't cover creating a custom widget when Kendo is used with AngularJS, which, granted, is not what the OP asked, but would still be very helpful to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! With this help I can do that:

```
kendo.data.DataSource.prototype.dataFiltered = function () {
    // Gets the filter from the dataSource
    var filters = this.filter();

    // Gets the full set of data from the data source
    var allData = this.data();

    // Applies the filter to the data
    var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);

    // Returns the filtered data
    return query.filter(filters).data;
}
```