# I want to display the applied filter criteria on the Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I display any applied filter criteria on the Kendo UI Grid.
I would like to have a readonly display, of the applied criteria.
Current functionality does allow user to apply filter, but that the user has to go to the filter menu to look for the filter details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Kendo UI data source doesn't have a filter event, so you'd need to implement that yourself. Then when the event is triggered, you can get the current filter and format it in whatever way you want it displayed.

For example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid(...);

// override the original filter method in the grid's data source
grid.dataSource.originalFilter = grid.dataSource.filter;
grid.dataSource.filter = function () {
    var result = grid.dataSource.originalFilter.apply(this, arguments);
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.trigger("afterfilter", arguments);
    }

    return result;
}

// bind to your filter event
grid.dataSource.bind("afterfilter", function () {
    var currentFilter = this.filter(); // get current filter

    // create HTML representation of the filter (this implementation works only for simple cases)
    var filterHtml = "";
    currentFilter.filters.forEach(function (filter, index) {
        filterHtml += "Field: " + filter.field + "<br/>" +
            "Operator: " + filter.operator + "<br/>" +
            "Value: " + filter.value + "<br/><br/>";

        if (currentFilter.filters.length > 1 && index !== currentFilter.filters.length - 1) {
            filterHtml += "Logic: " + currentFilter.logic + "<br/><br/>";
        }
    });

    // display it somewhere
    $("#filter").html(filterHtml);
});
```

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/7T8gb/).

Note that filters can be nested, so once that happens, this example code won't be enough - you'll have to make the code that converts the filters to HTML recursive.

In order to augment all data sources with the "afterfilter" event, you have to change the DataSource protototype instead of changing it on your instance:

```
kendo.data.DataSource.fn.originalFilter = kendo.data.DataSource.fn.filter;
kendo.data.DataSource.fn.filter = function () {
    var result = this.originalFilter.apply(this, arguments);
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.trigger("afterfilter", arguments);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you want to integrate the whole thing into all grid widgets, you could create a new method `filtersToHtml` which gets you the HTML represenatation and add it to `kendo.data.DataSource.fn` like demonstrated above (or you could [create your own widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20081407/2001735) derived from Kendo's grid); in the same way you could add a method `displayFilters` to `kendo.ui.Grid.fn` (the grid prototype) which displays this HTML representation in a DOM element whose selector you could pass in with the options to your widget (you could ultimately also create this element within the grid widget). Then instead of triggering "afterfilter" in the filter method, you could call `displayFilters` instead.

Considering the complexity of the complete implementation which always displays filters, I'd suggest extending the Kendo grid instead of simply modifying the original code. This will help keep this more maintainable and gives it a bit of structure.

Comment: How can I have this logic as part of the gird itself. Using this example, I will have to have this custom logic for every grid I use.

I want to display the applied filter as part of the grid itself.  So basically have to extend the Grid functionality.

Comment: @Kish_ore I updated my answer with a few ideas that should allow you to implement what you're after

Comment: I've included a KendoGridExtension class in JS to add additional functionality to the grid (persistent checkboxes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

how about combining two filters of grid.
this way the user can see the selected filter in text box and even remove it by hitting the 'x' button on filtered column text box.

you can do this by setting grid filterable like this

```
filterable: {
        mode: "menu, row"
    }
```

the documentation and example is in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.mode)