# Catching Kendo UI Grid filter changed event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to catch the filter changed event on a kendo grid? I need to run some logic when the filter is changed on my pages.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446071/i-want-to-display-the-applied-filter-criteria-on-the-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: what filtering do you use ? server or client

Comment: Try [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/any-filtering-event)

Comment: @cwishva client side filtering

Answer (score 1):

You just bind the "change" event on the Datasource, this event will be fired after filter run (and also in others times like when you populate the datasource)

```
dataSource: {
    data: createRandomData(50),
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                City: { type: "string" },
                Title: { type: "string" },
                BirthDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    },
    change: function(e) {
        Console.log('filtered'); //this will fire after filtered.
    },
    pageSize: 15
},
```