# Create custom reusable control in Javascript (Kendo UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-controls, kendo-ui

We're building a web app based on Microsoft MVC 4, but using KendoUI on the client side. **But we're not using the version of Kendo built for MVC, we use the web version.** What we're trying to do is create a kind of "user control". An address control that could be reuse on multiple page and even be added more than once on the same page. This controls should have multiple field with validation events bound to a model (Door number, street, city, state, etc.). Is it possible to do such kind of things ? My concern is especially about the events for disctinct fields. I have no clue about how to do such thing because I don't know how to create disctinct DOM ids for the inner input controls.

So if you have any reading or sample to suggest, that would make my day. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20081407/2001735) on how to create custom widgets. You can create distinct DOM ids in many ways, e.g. by deriving them from the id of the element the widget is created on (e.g. by appending "-my-special-field"). This would only work if you make sure these elements have an id, of course. Another option would be to have a global function to create unique ids with a counter, e.g. something like this:

```
var counter = -1;
var idPrefix = "my-awesome-app-";
function getUniqueId() {
    counter += 1;
    return idPrefix + counter;
}
```

Comment: That seems great ! I give it a try and mark it as the answer if it works. Thanks for your help !